# Using Option all over the place feels a bit awkward. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: scala, scala-option

As a result of articles I read about the `Option` class which helps you avoid NullPointerException's, I started to use it all over the place. Imagine something like this:

```
var file:Option[File] = None
```

and later when I use it:

```
val actualFile = file.getOrElse(new File("nonexisting"))
if(actualFile.getName.equals("nonexisting")) { // instead of null checking

}
else { // value of file was good

}
```

Doing stuff like this doesn't feel all that "right" to me. I also noticed that `.get` has become deprecated. . Is this sort of stuff what you guys are doing with Option's too, or am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to return `Option` and then use `getOrElse` to produce some sentinel value that means "not found".  That's what `Option` is designed for: to signify that a value is not found!

`Option` really shows its power when used in conjunction with functional programming constructs like `map` and `foreach`.  This is most potent when dealing with multiple options.  For example, suppose I write a method that takes a string and gives me back a file, but only if the file exists and is a file not a directory:

```
import java.io._;
def niceFile1(s: String): File = {
  val f = new File(s);
  if (f.exists && !f.isDirectory) f else null
}
def niceFile2(s: String): Option[File] = {
  val f = new File(s);
  if (f.exists && !f.isDirectory) Some(f) else None
}
```

So far, using `null` is easier--at least until you forget that this might give you `null` and you get a NPE.  Anyway, let's now try to use it.

```
def niceFopen1(s: String) = {
  val f = niceFile1(s);
  if (f!=null) new FileInputStream(f) else null;
}
def niceFopen2(s: String) = niceFile2(s).map(f => new FileInputStream(f))
```

Look what happened!  In the former case, we had to do logic tests by hand and create temporary variables.  Ugh!  In the second case, `map` did all the dirty work for us: None was mapped to None, and `Some(file)` was mapped to `Some(fileinputstream)`.  Easy!

But it gets better yet.  Maybe we want to find the size of a whole bunch of files:

```
def totalSize2(ss: Seq[String]) = {
  (0L /: ss.flatMap(niceFile2)){(sum,f) => sum+f.length}
}
```

Wait, what is going on here--what about all the `None`?  Don't we have to pay attention and handle them somehow?  Well, that's where `flatMap` comes in: it joins together all the answers into a single list.  `None` is an answer of length zero, so it ignores it.  `Some(f)` has one answer--`f`--so it puts it in the list.  Then we use a fold to add up all the lengths--now that all the elements in the list are valid.  Pretty nice!

Comment: I think that your first comment (i.e. resolving option via `getOrElse` being *a bad thing*) is far too general. There are plenty of examples where `getOrElse` might be used to provide a default value. For example, where to create temporary files might be overridable via some command-line property but you still ultimately want to **resolve a value**.

Comment: I specifically said a _sentinel_ value, not a _default_ value.  I agree that defaults are useful.  Sentinels--an object whose only purpose is to indicate some exceptional condition or end of list or whatever--almost never are.  Perhaps the phrasing I chose is subject to misinterpretation, however.

Comment: @RexKerr, why are sentintel values usually not useful?

Comment: @Kevin - Because when you roll your own you introduce a bunch of corner cases of "what about if this is actually the sentinel!".  It's usually better to use generic code that represents this condition well than roll your own and forget some case.  Of course, in some key cases sentinels are essential.  But the temptation occurs far more often--if you're not using something like Option--than it is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

It's a good idea to **not resolve** the value of the `Option`, but to *apply* logic to whatever is it contains:

```
findFile.foreach(process(_))
```

Basically this processes a `File` if one is found and does nothing otherwise (and is equivalent to Thomas' first `for` comprehension because `for` compiles to a call to `foreach`). It is a more concise version of:

```
findFile match {
  case Some(f) => process(f)
  case None =>
}
```

What's more, the great thing about this is that you can *chain* operations, something like:

```
(findLiveFile orElse fileBackupFile orElse findTempFile).foreach(process(_)
```

Comment: Won't this fail silently if it doesn't contain a value?

Comment: What do you mean "fail"? It won't do anything but this does not necessarily indicate failure! Obviously if you want to catch the "null case" (perhaps to emit a log message or a warning) then you would use pattern matching as Thomas has described

Answer (score 7):

In most cases you would use pattern matching

```
file match {
   case Some(f) => { .. } //file is there
   case _ => { .. } //file is not there 
}
```

If you're only interested in the file if it is there you can use a for expression

```
for(f <- file) { //file is there 
}
```

You can then chain for expressions to work on multiple levels on containers

```
for{ 
  option <- List(Some(1), None, Some(2))
  f <- option
} yield f

res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Alternatively you can use isDefined and get:

```
if(option.isDefined) {
   val x = option.get;
} else {
}
```

get is not deprecated in Scala 2.8.0.Beta-1.

Comment: Isn't that `file match` instead of `matches`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative:

```
var file:Option[File] = None
// ...
file map (new File(_)) foreach { fh =>
  // ...
}
```

However, if you need to do something if the file exists, and something else if it does not, a `match` statement is more appropriate:

```
var file:Option[File] = None
// ...
file map (new File(_)) match {
  case Some(fh) =>
    // ...
  case None =>
    // ...
}
```

That's pretty much the same as an `if` statement, but I like it's chaining nature better for things like `Option`, where I want to extract a value as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly restating what everyone is saying, but I think there's at least 4 different situations you will encounter when you have a nullable var like this:

1. The file must not be null

```
load(file.get())
```

Will throw an exception when you try to actually use the file.  Fail fast, yay!

2. The file is null, but in this case we have a sensible default:

```
load(file.getOrElse(new File("/defaultFile")))
```

3. Two branches of logic based on whether the file exists:

```
  file match {
    case Some(f) => { .. } //file is there
    case _ => { .. } //file is not there 
  }
```

4. No-op if the file is null, aka silently fail.  I don't think this one is very often preferable for me in real life:

```
for (f <- file) {
//do some stuff
}
```

Or, maybe more clearly?

```
if (f.isDefined) {
  //do some stuff
}
```